# Applying a percentage operation on a decimal type

Tags: c#, sql-server, math, decimal

I have seven decimals which are stored in a SQL Server database as type `decimal(17, 4)`. Precision is important as this is financial data.

I need to return 60% of the sum of the decimals as a decimal rounded to 6 places. So the operation is like `decimal result = (val1 + val2 + val3 + val4 + val5 + val6 + val7) * 0.6;`. This won't compile because '*' can't be used between decimal and double.

So that is my question - how do I get 60% of the sum of seven decimals, and return it as a decimal rounded to 6 places?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
  decimal result = (val1 + val2 + val3 + val4 + val5 + val6 + val7) * 0.6M; // <- 0.6M is Decimal, not Double
```

"M" suffix means "Decimal"

Answer (score 0):

In you example 0.6 is by default being considered as double. You need to convert it to decimal like this

```
 decimal v1 = 1.2222m, v2 = 2.222m, v3 = 3.333m;
 decimal result = (v1 + v2 + v3) * .6m;
```

Note the suffix `m` i have applied. it tells the compiler that treat this as a decimal.
Following are few other suffixes that can be user

```
// Use long suffix.
long l1 = 10000L;

// Use double suffix.
double d1 = 123.764D;

// Use float suffix.
float f1 = 100.50F;

// Use unsigned suffix.
uint u1 = 1000U;

// Use decimal suffix.
decimal m2 = 4000.1234M;

// Use unsigned suffix and long suffix.
ulong u2 = 10002000300040005000UL;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the result as decimal rouded to 6 decimal places do this:

```
decimal result = decimal.Round(((val1 + val2 + val3 + val4 + val5 + val6 + val7) * 0.6m), 6);
//the second parameter (the 6)means how many decimal places.
```

Forgott to tell you,in this method you can pass a third parameter of type MidpointRounding that specifies how to round.

Comment: Wanted to mark as the answer because terry bozzio really can play. Thanks for the rounding info.